# Why can't I call onFire();

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to implement weapon firing in my game!

My inheritance chain looks like this:

ACharacter -> AMainCharacter

AActor -> AWeapon -> ALaserGun

I'm trying to call a function in the `ALaserGun` class, but for some reason `Weapon` isn't of type `ALaserGun`. How can I use `SpawnActor<>()` to spawn an actor that's the same type as WeaponAtSpawnClass if I'm setting WeaponAtSpawnClass in blueprint? Right now, I'm spawning an `AWeapon` actor. I want to spawn a child of `AWeapon` which has `OnFire()` in it. The type of `Weapon` being the class stored in `WeaponAtSpawnClass`.

Some things that I've noted that might be causing the issue:

`Weapon` in MainCharacter.h is of type `AWeapon*`

`SpawnActor<>()` in Main Character.cpp uses `AWeapon` as the spawned type.

Would I have to change `AWeapon` in these statements to something else?

Here's my code:

**MainCharacter.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Character.h"
#include "MainCharacter.generated.h"

class AWeapon;

UCLASS()
class TEST_API AMainCharacter : public ACharacter
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    AWeapon* Weapon;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    TSubclassOf<AWeapon> WeaponAtSpawnClass;

    void OnFire();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    // Called to bind functionality to input
    virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent) override;
```

**MainCharacter.cpp**

```
#include "MainCharacter.h"
#include "Weapon.h"

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void AMainCharacter::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
    Weapon = GetWorld()->SpawnActor<AWeapon>(WeaponAtSpawnClass);
}

void AMainCharacter::OnFire()
{
    Weapon->OnFire();
}

// Called to bind functionality to input
void AMainCharacter::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);

    PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("Fire", IE_Pressed, this, &AMainCharacter::OnFire);
}
```

**Weapon.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "Weapon.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class TEST_API AWeapon : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

};
```

**There is no code in Weapon.cpp**

**LaserGun.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Weapon.h"
#include "LaserGun.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class TEST_API ALaserGun : public AWeapon
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:

    void OnFire();
};
```

**LaserGun.cpp**

```
#include "LaserGun.h"

void ALaserGun::OnFire()
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Gun fired"))
}
```

Comment: `AWeapon` needs `virtual void OnFire();` maybe `virtual void OnFire()=0;` depending on if all subclasses will have an OnFire() method

Comment: ***How can I use SpawnActor<>() to spawn an actor that's the same type as WeaponAtSpawnClass if I'm setting WeaponAtSpawnClass in blueprint?*** `c++` does not exactly work the way you want it to work in that OnFire() must be a member of `AWeapon` for `Weapon->OnFire();` to work as it is. Nothing you do with `SpawnActor<>()` will remove this requirement.

Answer (score 3):

`AWeapon* Weapon;` declares a pointer to any `AWeapon`. How whould the compiler know, that it points to a instance of a class that has some specific method?

Of course you could start casting `Weapon` to `ALaserGun`, but that's going to result in a mess. The better alternative is to declare the method in the interface `AWeapon`:

```
UCLASS()
class TEST_API AWeapon : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
 public:  
    virtual OnFire() = 0;
};
```

And for good style declare that you override that method:

```
UCLASS()
class TEST_API ALaserGun : public AWeapon
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    void OnFire() override;
};
```

---

Naming is of course up to you, for example, if not every weapon can fire, name the method `OnAttack` or something, then call `OnFire` from `OnAttack` or something like that.